# Drop Multiple table

Tags: mysql

How to drop multiple Table in  MySQL Database.
(Table have same suffix) Please Give me some idea ?

I am trying to drops multiple table having  same Suffix 00000

Query I am aplying is

```
Drop table Like '%00000';
```

Comment: You can use `show tables from db like '%00000'`
And then copy paste into a text editor and build a comma separated list to feed `drop table `.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one procedure

```
drop procedure if exists droplike;
delimiter //
create procedure droplike(pattern varchar(20))
begin
  set group_concat_max_len = 65535;
  select @drop:= concat( 'drop table ', group_concat(table_name) , ';' ) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = "database_name" and table_name like pattern;
  prepare statement from @drop;
  execute statement;
end //
delimiter ;
```

Then, call your procedure like below

```
call droplike("0000%");
```